# PyQt5 GUI order of line execution after connected button-press

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

My issue is with the order of execution of the lines in function connected to QPushButtons.

The order of execution ignores a command to disable the button until after other actions are completed, whereas I want it to be disabled immediately.

The behavior is the same whether

- the button is connected to a separate "disable" function first
- the disable function reference is included in the connected function
- the command to disable the button itself is rolled into the connected function.

Those three scenarios are produced in buttons 1, 2 and 3.

```
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QDialog,
    QGridLayout,
    QLabel,
    QPushButton,
    )

class VMC_View(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Disable-5-11')
        
        # header
        header_txt = "Disable button, wait 5sec, print 11"
        head_lab = '<h2 style="text-align:center">' + header_txt + '</h2>'
        self.header = QLabel(head_lab)
                
        # Define butts
        self.butt1 = QPushButton('butt 1 (two mthds)')
        self.butt2 = QPushButton('butt 2 (same mthd)')
        self.butt3 = QPushButton('butt 3 (same mthd eg2)')
        
        # set layout
        my_constWin = QGridLayout()
        my_constWin.addWidget(self.header, 0, 0)
        my_constWin.addWidget(self.butt1, 1, 0)
        my_constWin.addWidget(self.butt2, 2, 0)
        my_constWin.addWidget(self.butt3, 3, 0)
        self.setLayout(my_constWin)
        
    # for active button setting
    def set_button(self, button, state):
        if state == "enabled":
            button.setEnabled(True)
        if state == "disabled":
            button.setEnabled(False)

class VMC_Model():  
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view

    def disable_b1(self):
        self.view.set_button(self.view.butt1, "disabled")
            
    def wait_5_print_eleven(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        print('11')
        
    def dis_w5_pr11(self):
        self.view.set_button(self.view.butt2, "disabled")
        time.sleep(5)
        print('11')
        
    def disII_w5_pr11(self):
        self.view.butt3.setEnabled(False)
        time.sleep(5)
        print('11')

class VMC_Controller:
    """Controller Class"""
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self.model = model  
        self.view = view
        self._connectSignals()

    def _connectSignals(self):
        """Connect signals and slots"""
        self.view.butt1.clicked.connect(self.model.disable_b1)
        self.view.butt1.clicked.connect(self.model.wait_5_print_eleven)
        self.view.butt2.clicked.connect(self.model.dis_w5_pr11)
        self.view.butt3.clicked.connect(self.model.disII_w5_pr11)


# MAIN 

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Instantiate view
    myview = VMC_View()  # passing gui resource
    # Instantiate model
    mymodel = VMC_Model(view = myview) # pass view and modres
    # Instantiate controller
    VMC_Controller(model = mymodel, view = myview)
    # show GUI
    myview.show()
    # Execute GUI's main loop
    sys.exit(myApp.exec())

# INCLUDE - END(MAIN)
```

Comment: Remember that Qt, like all GUI frameworks, is event-driven.  When you call "disable", nothing happens immediately.  That simply sends a message.  The message will be fetched and dispatched when your handler returns and the main loop gets a chance to run again.  State does not change immediately,

Comment: It's also important to understand that if you put blocking functions, you're preventing immediate handling of events, but those won't be ignored, they will be *queued*. If you click on a disabled button *while* a function is blocking and is immediately followed by the button re-enabling, then the click will be catched anyway, because it will be processed *after* it.

Comment: Replace `time.sleep(5); print('11')` with `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: print('11'))`.